# What is the exact meaning of "crunching" and "knuckles" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

Crunching so many numbers that my knuckles hurt.

Comment: It's a pun of sorts, though if you have arthritis of the hands then your knuckles may actually hurt from too much keyboard activity.

Comment: Can you edit and give a lot more context, at least the previous couple sentences?

Answer (score 2):

***Crunching numbers*** is usually taken as doing a lot of calculations in order to find an answer.

But I have no idea why the knuckles will hurt. It sounds like the man was literally "crunching on" the numbers with his knuckles.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input.  Unfortunately, I don't have the context.

Answer (score 1):

One definition of "crunch" is:

> Process large amounts of information or perform operations of great complexity, especially by computer. [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/crunch)]

**so "crunching numbers" essentially means:**

> Performing operations with numbers.

---

The part about "knuckles" isn't as simple.

The author seems to be using "crunching" **metaphorically** (in addition to the definition above).

The author urges the reader to imagine someone *literally* crunching numbers (a *physical* representation of numbers) with their fists to the point where their knuckles hurt.

---

***Edit:** As BoldBen pointed out, their knuckles could be hurting because they have been typing on a keyboard for a prolonged period of time (while crunching numbers).  This would not be metaphorical and is the more likely situation because "crunching numbers" is usually done on a computer.*

Comment: Wow, Sir, you have a logical perspective in this regards.

Comment: @Safalta Thank you!  I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: I also think that it could be to do with the use of a computer keyboard. Also there's a neat pun on "crunching knuckles" which is what we call the noise that some people can make by stretching and compressing the joints of their fingers.

Comment: @BoldBen I hadn't thought of that, but it is definitely plausible.  I assumed that, because we were provided no context, we were to assume that no computer was involved.  Still, the use of "crunching numbers" is usually paired with a computer.  Thanks for your (very insightful) contribution.

Answer (score 0):

The basic meaning of crunch is to put something under pressure, especially to chew something crunchy with you teeth, like potato chips; or to crunch leaves (or snow) on a path underfoot as you walk; or crunch a piece of paper in your hand into a ball before you throw it away. And crunches are like sit-ups, the exercise you do for your abs. So crunching numbers is an analogy to these physical activities. hard work. thus sore knuckles.